# converting a 16 bit Boolean array to a integer

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have found out how to do the opposite of converting a integer to a 16 bit Boolean array by this.

```
 Dim ND1_Array As New System.Collections.BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(Data(2)))
```

I have tried this

```
Dim barray(15) As Boolean : barray(0) = True : barray(2) = True : barray(4) = True
    Dim bittoint As Integer
    bittoint = Convert.ToInt32(barray(0), 0)
```

This code throws an error so ?
I have looked all over the net but can't find how to do this.

```
bittoint = BitConverter.ToInt32(barray(0), 0)
```

This has an error as well
Error   1   Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.   C:\PLC\TCPClientClean\TCPClientClean\ChatClient.vb  201 41  TCPClientClean

This is what I came up with.  Not sure what is the better method? I just saw the new updated code that was provided.

```
Dim BoolStg As String
    Dim BoolArra1DexBit As Boolean
    Dim BitArray1ToInt16 As Integer
    For BarryDex = 0 To 15
        BoolArra1DexBit = BoolAray1(BarryDex)
        If BoolArra1DexBit = True Then
            BoolStg = "1" & BoolStg
        Else : BoolStg = "0" & BoolStg
        End If
    Next
    BitArray1ToInt16 = Convert.ToInt16(BoolStg, 2)
```

Comment: a more detailed error description please.

Comment: Invalid base
and this in the immediate window
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: you feed toint32 with a boolean, there is no second parameter here.

Comment: Try `BitConverter.ToInt16/32` instead.

Comment: Oh, and you need to set [option strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **`on`**.

Comment: You'll have to use BitArray.CopyTo().  Declare an integer array with 1 element.

Comment: OK I am unfamiliar with the option strict {ON} as to where to put it and what that exactly dose. I looked up the link you @Bj0rn shared but am lost.. Not that experienced just yet..

Comment: put it very above in the first line of your code window

Comment: @ Bj0rn,  I tried the option strict on and got 14 errors on build ?
@Hans , Meaning the integer I put the Boolean array into has to be a array also? I am not sure how to write that out in code but kind of understand..

Comment: @ms_ssccControls Those 14 errors with Option Strict On are statements that will compile with Option Strict Off, but might result in errors at runtime. It would be a good idea to correct all those error.

Comment: Is that `Binary 1010100000000000 = Decimal 43,008`, or `Binary 0000000000010101 = Decimal 21`?

Answer (score 1):

little example

```
    Dim myFlags As Integer = &H11
    MsgBox(Convert.ToString(myFlags, 2))

    Dim ND1_Array As New System.Collections.BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(myFlags))

    Dim myFlags_tmparray(0) As Integer
    ND1_Array.CopyTo(myFlags_tmparray, 0)

    MsgBox(Convert.ToString(myFlags_tmparray(0), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that will return the integer equivalent as little endian or big endian, and allows you to toggle TwosComplement as well:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim barray(15) As Boolean : barray(0) = True : barray(2) = True : barray(4) = True

        Dim BigEndianInteger As Integer = barray.ToInteger(False)
        Dim LittleEndianInteger As Integer = barray.ToInteger() ' <-- default is Little Endian with TwosComplement turned On

        Debug.Print("BigEndianInteger = " & BigEndianInteger)
        Debug.Print("LittleEndianInteger = " & LittleEndianInteger)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module Extensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ToInteger(ByVal BooleanArray() As Boolean, Optional ByVal LittleEndian As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal TwosComplement As Boolean = True) As Integer
        If BooleanArray.Length <= 32 Then
            Dim sum As Integer
            Dim values As New List(Of Boolean)(BooleanArray)
            If Not LittleEndian Then
                values.Reverse()
            End If
            For i As Integer = 0 To values.Count - 1
                If values(i) Then
                    If i < (values.Count - 1) Then
                        sum = sum + Math.Pow(2, i)
                    ElseIf TwosComplement Then
                        sum = sum - Math.Pow(2, i)
                    Else
                        sum = sum + Math.Pow(2, i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            Return sum
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Boolean array length must be less than or equal to 32.")
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: It was Little endian  and your code worked very well !! Thanks

Comment: This code that you provided @Idle_Mind  works well except for when bit 15 of the array is true.  For example 
    Barray1 = 100000000000000

Comment: This code that you provided @Idle_Mind  works well except for when bit 15 of the array is true.  For example 
     Barray1 = 1000000000000000
     LittleEndian = 32768 ?  It should be -32768
     Barray1 = 1111111111111111
     LittleEndian = 65535  ? It should be -1 by any binary to int conversion?

Comment: Ah...you never specified **signed** or **unsigned**.  What [signed number representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) are you using here?

Comment: I am only about 6 months into learning vb.  I normal write code for PLC's Programmable Logic Controllers.  When those controllers convert it is just has a drop down list that will change from 16 bit binary, octal, decimal, Hex/BCD, ASCII.  To me it is just a standard conversion that I am used to.. I just use a binary to integer calculator to find a conversion.  I hope that is enough information to explain witch singed number representation..  I just need the conversion like a standard binary calculator would convert to integer/ decimal value. Hope this helps. Thx

Comment: Well, what should `1000000000000000` be?...or how about `1000000`?  Punch those into your converter and report back what numbers you get.  There isn't really a **standard**, only different ways of doing it (resulting in very different numbers).  Did you read the link?

Comment: Yes I read the link.   I believe it is Two's complementary that I want to use but am not sure.   ** 1000000000000000 should = -32768**  **1100000000000000 should = -16384**  **1110000000000000 should = -8192 **    **1000000000000001 should = -32767 **  0000000000001111 should = 15 **  **1100000000001111 should = --16369 ** I hope this helps

Comment: Added TwosComplement support.